# Set Key to submit selection in editor and make editor the active window again

Tags: sas

I am trying to configure the F3 key so that it

1. Submits code in the editor window (either all or selection)
2. Updates the results window
3. Put focus back on the editor/or let focus remain in editor

The default behavior of the F3 button is to submit the code in editor, but then to focus on the results window, forcing me to reach for the mouse, to continue editing.

I have tried to configure F3 key like this but it does not work, because focus is on results windows after submitting:

```
F3      submit; wpgm ;
```

Any ideas?

I'm using:
SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M3
X64_8PRO platform 
Windows 10

I think this is also called "Display Manager", although I used to refer to it as SAS Base.

Comment: Your suggested `submit;wpgm;` seems to work for me.  With just submit, I end up with the OUTPUT window active, which is different than the RESULTS window.  But it's possible I have other options set differently.   When you say "results window" do you mean perhaps a PDF doc or similar you are creating?  Maybe turn off Tools->Options->Preferences View Results As They Are Generated.

Comment: Thanks. By "results window" i mean a window called "Results Viewer - sashtml.htm" which I think is the SAS internal browser showing html. When I follow your suggestion and turn off "View results as they are generated" the cursor F3 makes the cursor stay active in the editor window, however no results are generated (I want results to be generated, but the cursor be active in the editor window).

Comment: I assume you are using Display Manger. Can you confirm your operating system and SAS version?